# Firestore query StartAt(DocumentReference) not giving proper result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore database,there are 12+ documents.I am getting the first 3 documents correctly by calling the below function `on button click`. But on the `secondclick`, though the documentReference is passed correctly, its not retrieving any data.The querySnapshot size is coming 0. What could be the problem.

Given below is the declaration

```
private val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private val colRef: CollectionReference = db.collection("Notebook")
private var lastResult: DocumentReference? = null
private lateinit var query: Query
```

and below is the `onButtonClick` code :

```
private fun loadNoteNew() {
    @Suppress("SENSELESS_COMPARISON", "LiftReturnOrAssignment")
    if (lastResult == null) {
        query = colRef.orderBy("priority")
            .limit(3)
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Start ${lastResult!!.id}")
        query = colRef.orderBy("priority")
            .startAfter(lastResult)
            .limit(3)
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "before get")
    query.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
            var data = ""
            Log.i(TAG, "querySnapshot Size : ${querySnapshot.size()}")
            if (lastResult != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "querySnapshot ID : ${lastResult!!.id}")
            }


            for (snapshot in querySnapshot) {
                val note = snapshot.toObject(Note::class.java)
                note.id = snapshot.id

                val title = note.title
                val desc = note.description
                val priority = note.priority
                data += "${note.id} \nTitle =$title \nDescription = $desc\nPriority : $priority\n\n"
            }
            if (querySnapshot.size() > 0) {
                data += "---------------\n\n"
                textView_loadData.append(data)
                lastResult = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.size() - 1].reference
                Log.i(TAG, lastResult!!.id)
            }
        }
}
```

Given below is the logcat for first click

```
I/FireStoreExample: before get
I/FireStoreExample: querySnapshot Size : 3
I/FireStoreExample: P9hIw4Ai7w4IHP6H3ew3
```

and given below is the logcat of second click

```
I/FireStoreExample: Start P9hIw4Ai7w4IHP6H3ew3
I/FireStoreExample: before get
I/FireStoreExample: querySnapshot Size : 0
I/FireStoreExample: querySnapshot ID : P9hIw4Ai7w4IHP6H3ew3
```

Please help me find out,where i am getting it wrong.
Thanks

Comment: You are not actually using startAt but startAfter and you have a limit set to 3, therefore it will only return you 3 elements
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data

Answer (score 1):

The second query result is empty because of a misunderstanding on the semantics of query pagination using **startAt** and **startAfter** methods.

Let's say the Notebook collection contains N documents. When you make the first query you're asking for the first 3 documents ordered by the priority field so the query is returning documents 1..3. Then upon the second click you're expecting the query to return the next 3 results so indeed you're expecting documents 4..6. The keypoint here is that both **startAt** and **startAfter** paginate based on the value of the ordered field rather than with the last document retrieved. Overall the semantics of startAt and startAfter are roughly as follows.

orderby(X).startAt(Y) => Return documents whose X field is greater than or equal Y
orderby(X).startAfter(Y) => Return documents whose X field is strictly greater than Y

With that in mind, let's examine what the code is actually doing when you make the second query:

```kotlin
// At the end of the first query...
lastResult = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.size() - 1].reference

// Second query
query = colRef.orderBy("priority")
            .startAfter(lastResult)
            .limit(3)
```

In the code above you're asking for the documents whose "priority" field is greater than document reference "P9hIw4Ai7w4IHP6H3ew3" and indeed there are no documents greater than that, therefore the result set is empty. Here is [api reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#public-query-startafter-documentsnapshot-snapshot) for both.

There is yet another thing to note. Because these methods filter upon the fields value the position of the cursor could be ambiguous. For instance, if you have 4 documents with priority 3 and already retrieved the leading three if you set `startAfter(3)` you'll be missing a document. Similarly, if `startAt(3)` were to be made you'll get back the same three documents. This is also pointed out in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#set_cursor_based_on_multiple_fields). All in all you have a couple of options to make this work as intended:

Add another orderby in another field so that documents are uniquely identified by the combination so to prevent any cursor ambiguity and be able to use **startAfter** with guarantees. Next snippet build upon the doc samples and your code.

```kotlin
// first query
query = colRef.orderBy("priority")
              .orderBy("AnotherField")
              .limit(3)
// Save last document
lastResult = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.size() - 1]

// Second and next queries
query = colRef.orderBy("priority")
              .orderBy("AnotherField")
              .startAfter(lastResult)
              .limit(3)
```

Lastly remember that it might be simpler to just query all the documents if they're not many and delay optimizations until they become a performance issue.